# How to control other buttons' actions?

Tags: iphone

Hi so say I have this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle: @"Yay"
message: msg
delegate: self
cancelButtonTitle: @"Proceed..."
otherButtonTitles: @"1", @"2", nil];
```

How do I control the other buttons "1" and "2"? (Suppose all other necessary code is in place, such as the undefined variable msg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW7) property of your `UIAlertView` instance (i.e. `alert`) and implement the method [`alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#jumpTo_3).

Let's assume that you want the current class to be the delegate of the UIAlertView. You would use the following line of code:

```
alert.delegate = self;
```

Next, you would setup the current class to implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in the .h file. For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then you would simply implement the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method in the .m file:

```
- alertView:a clickedButtonAtIndex:i {
  NSLog(@"You clicked %d.", i);
}
```